# Hide header on first page, but show footer

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I am making a template (dot) using Word 2010 and need the header not to show on just the first page, but the footer must appear on the first and everyother page.

Comment: There's the "Different First Page" option but that applies to **both** header and footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set a different header and footer for the first page. Then you can copy the standard footer in the first page footer and keep the first page header empty. That way, the first page will have a footer, and the rest of the pages will have footers and headers.

My version of Word is Dutch, but it is the checkbox at the top in the following screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of headers and footers]

Comment: "Different first page" probably, or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have word in front of me at the mo, but it would go something like this:

- Specify that you want different first page headers and footers.
- Create your subsequent page header and footer.
- Copy the subsequent page footer to the first page footer.
- Leave the first page header blank.